# Reading Telerik Spreasheet

Tags: .net, vb.net, telerik

I'm trying to read a Spreadsheet using Telerik.Windows.Documents.Spreadsheet.
No errors raised, however it loads no data and 0 Worksheets.
Am I missing an important step?

```
Dim workbook As New Workbook() 
Dim FilePath As String = "myFile.xlsx"
Dim webClient As New WebClient()

AddHandler webClient.OpenReadCompleted, Sub(sender, eventArgs)
                                                            Dim formatProvider As New XlsxFormatProvider()
                                                            workbook = formatProvider.Import(eventArgs.Result)
                                                        End Sub

webClient.OpenReadAsync(New Uri(FilePath))
Dim worksheet As Worksheet = workbook.Sheets(0) 'No sheet at index 0
```

Answer (score 0):

This Worked!

```
Dim workbook As New Workbook()
Dim fileName As String = "myFile.xlsx"
If Not File.Exists(fileName) Then
Throw New FileNotFoundException([String].Format("File {0} was not found!", fileName))
End If
Dim formatProvider As IWorkbookFormatProvider = New XlsxFormatProvider()
Using input As Stream = New FileStream(fileName, FileMode.Open)
workbook = formatProvider.Import(input)
End Using
```